# Hide a custom tab by javaScript only if webpart does not exist

Tags: jsom, custom-actions

I'm tying to hide a custom tab from a page only if a specific webpart does not exist on the page.
I have the following code to get the list of the webparts on the page. How can I hide the tab only if a webPart doesnot exists? In my code, the tab dissapears only if the webpart **exists**.
Another thing, the Js code runs only once and after the page refresh or loaded again the tab shows again...

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/...';
var serverRelativeUrl = '/sites/...Default.aspx';

function updateWebPartTitle() {
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oFile = clientContext.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);
    var limitedWebPartManager = oFile.getLimitedWebPartManager(SP.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.shared);
    this.collWebPart = limitedWebPartManager.get_webParts();
    this.flag = 'no';
    clientContext.load(collWebPart);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.changeTitle), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function changeTitle() {
    if (!collWebPart.get_count()) {
        alert('No Web Parts on this page.');
    } else {
        alert('webpart count on page:' + collWebPart.get_count());
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < collWebPart.get_count(); i++) {
        var webPartDef = collWebPart.get_item(i);
        alert(i);
        this.oWebPart = webPartDef.get_webPart();
        alert(i);
        clientContext.load(oWebPart, 'Title');
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        alert(this.flag);
    }
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Title for Web Part: ' + this.oWebPart.get_title());
    if (this.oWebPart.get_title() == 'web part title') {
        this.flag = 'yes';
        SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function() {
            'use strict ';
            var tabIdToRemove = 'Ribbon.CustomTabExample';
            var pageManager = SP.Ribbon.PageManager.get_instance();
            var ribbon = pageManager.get_ribbon();
            // Remove the tab whose id is specified via the "tabId" argument.
            var removeTab = function removeTab(tabId) {
                var ribbon = pageManager.get_ribbon();
                // Select the "BROWSE" tab.
                SelectRibbonTab('Ribbon.Read', true);
                // Remove the specified tab.
                ribbon.removeChild(tabId);
                alert(tabId + " is being removed by javascript");
            };
            // Add callback function after the ribbon object has been initialised.
            pageManager.add_ribbonInited(function() {
                removeTab(tabIdToRemove);
            });
            // Ensure that the ribbon object has been initialised before using it.
            // Otherwise initialise it.
            if (ribbon) {
                removeTab(tabIdToRemove);
            } else {
                if (typeof _ribbonStartInit === 'function') {
                    _ribbonStartInit(tabIdToRemove, false, null);
                }
            }
        }, 'sp.ribbon.js');
    }
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
updateWebPartTitle();
```

Comment: Regarding jquery being fired only once, Is the Minimal Download Strategy Feature activated in your Site Settings->Site Features ?